# Unload html page with jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code to load on a div whole page:

```
 $('.class').click(function(){
     $(this).load("file.php");
 });
```

The idea is, that whenever i click on "X" button in upper right corner i want to close this page. I was thinking about `.hide()`, but i guess it will be unnecessary all that time loaded right under parent site. Also i was considering something like `session destroy` since loaded page has `.php` end. I red few things about `.unload()` but it doesn't give any effects at all:

```
$('.escape-btn').click(function(){
    $(this).unload("file.php");
});
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand what is the purpose of `.load()` and `.unload()`.
They are used to bind event handlers or invoke `JS` events...

Comment: What method will you use to "close the page"? Do you want to remove HTML content or close a browser window?

Comment: Just to remove HTML content.

Comment: You could use `$('html').remove()`, but I don't see why would you do that.

Comment: Probably yes, but i thought that it could be outdated since it's been 6 years now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unload method is deprecated and is not for what you seem to be intending to do here.

If your goal is clear everything out, I would try $(this).empty()

https://api.jquery.com/empty/